# Java JFrame window is not updating

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've tried a lot of things but I still cannot figure it out. I have a `List` that contains "entities". I'm going trought all of these and rendering them. This works perfectly fine. The problem is that when I remove one object (entity) in this `List` from different thread. In this case the square (entity) won't disappear until I resize the window.

```
private List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

public void render(Graphics g, ImageObserver obs) { //This function is called from my game loop (few hundred times per second..)
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
        entities.get(i).render(); //Calling the render function in the entity class
    }
}

public void removeEntity(int index) { //This function is called from different thread
    entities.remove(index); //Removing entity from the list
}
```

Comment: Do you call `frame.repaint()`? (or just `repaint()` if this code is in the `JFrame` class)

Comment: Consider when you remove an Entity to call repaint()

Comment: No. I didn't know that it's needed. I was doing similiar things in Java but it worked without it. I think it was becouse I was filling the window with white color each render. I'm not doing this now. I'll try it.

Comment: I tried calling repaint() but it's still not working.

Comment: 1) Post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Your method render has a `Graphics g` parameter, but you don't do anything with it-->It is impossible to display something without accessing it.

Comment: Oh, I just forgot the put it here. The entities.get(i).render(g, obs); is actually taking the Graphics g parameter.

Comment: Now it works. I'm just filling the window with white color every render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `render()` function is not being called. You need to call `repaint()` to do this. This will call `render()` and update the JFrame. Resizing the window repaints the window automatically, which is why it worked only after you resized it.